# Failed to open error_log (/var/log/php-fpm.log): Permission denied

Tags: php7, nginx

Hola estoy intentando inicializar el servicio de php-fpm pero al hacerlo, me da un error y no he logrado resolverlo, estoy usando php7.4 . FREEBSD 13

```
user1@free1:~ % service php-fpm start
Performing sanity check on php-fpm configuration:
[06-Oct-2022 14:45:13] ERROR: failed to open error_log (/var/log/php-fpm.log): Permission denied (13)
[06-Oct-2022 14:45:13] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[06-Oct-2022 14:45:13] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/php-fpm: WARNING: failed precmd routine for php_fpm
fespinosa@free1:~ % ls /var/log/
auth.log        debug.log       maillog         messages        security        userlog
auth.log.0.bz2  devd.log        maillog.0.bz2   mount.today     sendmail.st     utx.lastlogin
bsdinstall_log  dmesg.today     maillog.1.bz2   nginx           sendmail.st.0   utx.log
cron            dmesg.yesterday maillog.2.bz2   php-fpm.log     sendmail.st.1   utx.log.0
daemon.log      lpd-errs        maillog.3.bz2   ppp.log         setuid.today    xferlog
user1@free1:~ %
```

Comment: usa `sudo` o el usuario `root` para poder ver el log

Comment: el archivo php-fpm.log lo cree yo manualmente como intento de posible solución,  que como decía que no se podía abrir el archivo y este no estaba creado pues intente crearlo manual, pero aun así no funciona. así que no contiene nada ese archivo, esta en blanco

Comment: prueba cambiandole el group/owner a `chown root:root` y ponle permisos 700 a ver si cuela. En mi server todos esos logs son así (`-rw-------   1 root        root                   0 Jan 30  2022 php8.0-fpm.log`)

Comment: con los permisos 700 no funciona, con 777 si y me tira esto:
`[06-Oct-2022 15:17:04] NOTICE: configuration file /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf test is successful

Starting php_fpm.
limits: setrlimit datasize: Operation not permitted
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/php-fpm: WARNING: failed to start php_fpm`

Comment: Revisa los pasos que has efectuado para la instalación de eso, porque me parece que algo has hecho mal y no es normal tener que ir cambiando permisos ni que aparezcan esos errores tan raros.  No se en que información te has basado para la instalación pero quizás deberías buscar otra información y mirar de hacerlo de otra manera.

Comment: Bueno, gracias igual, estoy utilizando -> [link](https://techviewleo.com/install-wordpress-with-nginx-php-fpm-on-freebsd/)

Comment: uf, FreeBSD 13, je, no es lo mio, suerte! :-)